# Elliptic pseudodifferential operator has at most finite number of non-positive eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $P \in OPS^m(M)$ ($m$ can be negative of positive) be a self-adjoint elliptic pseudodifferential operator on a compact manifold $M$. How to show that $P$ has only finitely many non-positive eigenvalues (in $L^2(M)$)? Does it somehow follow from the Gårding inequality?